# Powershell won't grab files

Tags: powershell

So I have a line in a PS script that is looking for a file older than X days in a given directory...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\fsrv02\FTP\AX\AXDropoff\PositivePay\Response\  "*.*" -Recurse |where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date}|Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending| Write-host
```

SO i am testing the line and I cannot get it to select any of the files in the folder.

When I take this part out:

```
|where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }|
```

It selects the archive directory in that folder because it's the oldest. But I want it to ignore the directories so I added that line, I'm sure I can combine it with the where-object, but not 100%...

The issue I have is that the files in the folder don't have a .txt extension. We pull them down from an FTP, and they all have like .45 or .40 or .00 file extensions...how can I have powershell look for these files accordingly...

My output when i run is that it is syntactically correct, but it just doesn't select anything

PS I have a $date variable that it looks for that is like this:

```
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-5)
```

Much appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for files older than `$date`, then the file time should be less than `$date`

```
where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}
```

Comment: Awesome, somewhat confusing I suppose because I'm looking for files that are OLDER than 5 days before today's date. So if I use the -gt...yep logic stops there. much rep for you. Good eye.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to filter the files with two digit extensions:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path \\fsrv02\FTP\AX\AXDropoff\PositivePay\Response\  "*.*" -Recurse
   | where{ $_.extension -match "\d\d"}
```

You can combine that with @Rynant's answer to hopefully get what you need.